# Harmonic functions and Markov processes

Tags: probability, markov-process

I was reading some lecture notes, in which it is stated that, given a discrete time Markov process $X_t$, for its Markov semigroup $P_t$ it holds that:
$$
P_tf(x) = E_x[f(X_t)]=E[f(X_t)|X_0=x]
$$
For each $f:S \to \mathbf{R}$ measurable and bounded. After this statement it is said that a bounded measurable function $f:S\to \mathbf{R}$ (where S is a Polish space endowed with its Borel σ-field) is said to be harmonic on D⊂S iff
$$ Lf(x)=0\ \forall x \in D$$
where $ L=P−1$ is the generator of the markov process. It is asked to prove that such a function $f $ is harmonic on $S$ if and only if the process $ f(X_t) $ is a martingale. I tried to prove it, and it is easy to see, using the fact that
$$M_t:=f(X_t)−f(X_0)−\sum_{s=0}^{t-1}Lf(X_s)$$
is a martingale, that $f(X_t)$ is a martingale if and only if $Lf(X_s)=0 \forall s \ge 0$. Now, if f is harmonic it is clear that $Lf(X_s)=0$, for the converse it seems that one should derive the fact that $ f $ is harmonic from$ Lf(X_0)=0$, indeed one has
$$0=Lf(X_0)=Pf(X_0)−f(X_0)$$
now, I was able to prove the following:

If $ g:S→\mathbf{R}$ is bounded and measurable, and such that
$$g(X_0)=E[f(X_t)|F_0]$$
then$ g(x)=E[f(Xt)|X_0=x]$, $P_{X_0}$-a.e.

Since we know that $ E[f(X_1)|X_0=x]=Pf(x)$, one gets that $P_{X_0}$-a.e.
$$f(x)=Pf(x)$$
and thus$ Lf(x)=0$, $P_{X_0}$-a.e. But I'm not able to prove that equality holds for every x. Do you have any idea?

Comment: "$f$ is harmonic on $S$ iff $f(X_t)$ is a martingale" ... a martingale with respect to which probability measure(s)? This is quite of importance at this point.

Comment: 1. We are assuming that all takes place in one probability space $(\Omega, \Sigma, \mathbb{P})$. A martingale with respect to this... 2. If you reread "$f$ is a martingale on $S$ iff $f(X_t)$ is a martingale", so we are taking $D=S$ and there's no problem

Comment: 2) I did reread it and already removed it from my comment. 1) If this is so, then why would you expect that the assertion holds true? Just consider for instance the constant process $X_t := 0$ and $\mathbb{P} := \delta_{x_0}$ for some fixed $x_0 \in S$ and $|S|>1$. Since the process doesn't "see" $S \backslash \{x_0\}$, we can hardly expect that $f(X_t)$ being a $\mathbb{P}$-martingale implies $Lf=0$ on $S$. Please correct me if I'm wrong.